# Azure cosmos DB Data migration tool getting error when verifying Connection string

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I currently have an azure cosmos db that i want to export file from. I am using the Azure cosmos DB Data migration tool for this process and on the first screen i am trying to verify my connection string to the db but am getting the following error:

```
Error reading Object from jsonReader.Path,line 0,position 0
```

I have verify that my connection string is in the format required and i have try the different connection method available.

Note: I am getting the same error when trying to use cosmisclone app.

Comment: Without seeing any details about things like the connection string you're passing, it's difficult to guess what's going wrong. Note: If you *do* share, please alter/remove the access key. That said: You've tagged this with both the SQL API and the MongoDB API. Which API is your Cosmos DB instance based on? This might be related to why you're getting the error, if you used a connection string type that's not expected. Oh, one more thing - the question itself is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question, more of a tool usage question.